# file disappears while moving because I typed the wrong directory

Tags: files, directory, mv, move

While moving a file, I typed

```
$ mv aaa.txt directory
```

instead of

```
$ mv aaa.txt ../directory
```

and now I don't know where `aaa.txt` has gone.  How can I find it?

Comment: Do you have a file in the current directory named `directory`?

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible scenarios.

(1) Suppose that you have:

```
├── bar
│   └── aaa.txt
└── foo
```

and you're currently in the directory `bar`, if you wanted to move `aaa.txt` to the directory `../foo`, but typed `mv aaa.txt foo`, then you would have renamed `aaa.txt` to `foo` within `bar`:

```
├── bar
│   └── foo <- this is your file now
└── foo
```

(2) Suppose that you have

```
├── bar
│   ├── aaa.txt
│   └── foo
└── foo
```

In this case you have two directories named `foo` one within `bar` and the other one in the same directory as `foo`.  If you typed `mv aaa.txt` from within `bar`, then that would move `aaa.txt` to the directory named `foo` in the current directory:

```
├── bar
│   └── foo
│       └── aaa.txt <- this is your file now
└── foo
```